# email whitelist/blacklist in python/django

Tags: python, django, email, whitelist, blacklist

I am writing a django app that keeps track of which email addresses are allowed to post content to a user's account. The user can whitelist and blacklist addresses as they like.

Any addresses that aren't specified can either be handled per message or just default to whitelist or blacklist (again user specified).

Here are the django models I wrote... do you think is a good way to do it? or should I add a whitelist and blacklist field to each user's profile model?

```
class knownEmail(models.Model):
    # The user who set this address' permission, NOT
    # the user who the address belongs to...
    relatedUser = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    email = models.EmailField()

class whiteList(knownEmail):
    pass

class blackList(knownEmail):
    pass
```

Then I could do something like:

```
def checkPermission(user, emailAddress):
    "Check if 'emailAddress' is allowed to post content to 'user's profile"
    if whiteList.objects.filter(relatedUser=user, email=emailAddress):
        return True
    elif blackList.objects.filter(relatedUser=user, email=emailAddress):
        return False
    else:
        return None
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would restructure it so both lists were contained in one model.

```
class PermissionList(models.Model):
    setter = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True) #don't want conflicting results
    permission = models.BooleanField()
```

Then, your lists would just be:

```
# whitelist
PermissionList.objects.filter(permission=True)
# blacklist
PermissionList.objects.filter(permission=False)
```

To check a particular user, you just add a couple functions to the model:

```
class PermissionList(...):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def is_on_whitelist(email):
        return PermissionList.objects.filter(email=email, permission=True).count() > 0

    @classmethod
    def is_on_blacklist(email):
        return PermissionList.objects.filter(email=email, permission=False).count() > 0

    @classmethod
    def has_permission(email):
        if PermissionList.is_on_whitelist(email):
            return True
        if PermissionList.is_on_blacklist(email):
            return False
        return None
```

Having everything in one place is a lot simpler, and you can make more interesting queries with less work.

Comment: thanks, I think your second class method should be is_on_blacklist though ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Please start All Class Names With Upper Case Letters.]

Your code doesn't make use of your class distinction very well.

Specifically, your classes don't have any different behavior.  Since both classes have all the same methods, it isn't clear *why* these are two different classes in the first place.   If they have different methods, then your solution is good.

If, however, they don't have different methods, you might want to look at providing a customized [manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#managers) for each of the two subsets of `KnownEmail`

```
class WhiteList( models.Manager ):
    def get_query_set( self ):
        return super( WhiteList, self ).get_query_set().filter( status='W' )

class BlackList( models.Manager )
    def get_query_set( self ):
        return super( BlackList, self ).get_query_set().filter( status='B' )

class KnownEmail( models.Model ):
    relatedUser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    email = models.EmailField()
    status = models.CharField( max_length=1, choices=LIST_CHOICES )
    objects = models.Manager() # default manager shows all lists
    whiteList= WhiteList() # KnownEmail.whiteList.all() is whitelist subset
    blackList= BlackList() # KnownEmail.blackList.all() is blackList subset
```

Answer (score 0):

This class compares an email address with a blacklist of email domains. If you preffer you can download this module using [pip install django-email-blacklist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=django-email-blacklist&version=1.0.1).

```
from django.conf import settings
import re

class DisposableEmailChecker():
"""
Check if an email is from a disposable
email service
"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.emails = [line.strip() for line in   open(settings.DISPOSABLE_EMAIL_DOMAINS)]

    def chunk(self, l, n):
        return (l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n))

    def is_disposable(self, email):
        for email_group in self.chunk(self.emails, 20):
            regex = "(.*" + ")|(.*".join(email_group) + ")"
                if re.match(regex, email):
                    return True
                return False
```